# A thanks to this network

Tags: discussion, thanks

Till now, I have learned a lot from this network. I believe that there is unlimited knowledge here. It is a good place to share and gain knowledge of almost all types. This network inspired all the skills in me.
I wanna pay thanks to this community.
Here are some gifts from me:

[image]

You can achieve all your goals with the help of this network:

[image]

*<sub>(Designed with Studio Bricklink)
(Rendered with Eyesight Bricklink)</sub>*

Also share your contributions and love for this network...

### Edit:

Here is another version of the first model:

[image]

### Edit 2:

Here is the Blender edition of that model rendered with cycles:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on-topic here, but I agree. This is a great network.

Comment: Thank you as well for your efforts!

Comment: @Glorfindel Nevermind. Took me 4+ hours to build and render

Comment: @Glorfindel My post is a bit different. The question you mentioned is asking about how to pay thanks, but I am not asking that. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That's correct, but the linked question states that the way to say thanks is to pay it forward and to upvote. The alternative would be to close it as too broad, primarily opinion-based and/or unclear what you're asking... Your intentions are clear, but it's not really a Q&A.

Comment: Excellent work, for a minute there I was fooled into thinking it was actual legos. Alas, Stack Overflow is not like Reddit where you have plenty of places to share your work and pay homage.

Comment: _but I am not asking that_ – What exactly is it that you're asking, then?

Comment: @forest There is no question, it is their way of saying "Thank you" to Stack Exchange.